# how to write switch case in php for two search fields, each fields consists of four select options

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
<form> 
    <label><font style="font-size:20px">Bases:</font></label>
    <select style="font-size:18px" name="select1" id="select1" >
        <option value="greaterthan" selected="selected">&gt;</option>
        <option value="greaterthanorequal">&ge;</option>
        <option value="lessthan">&lt;</option>
        <option value="lessthanorequal">&le;</option>
        <option value="equal">&#x3d;</option>
    </select>
    <input  type="text" name="bases" id="bases" placeholder="Eg:10125918250" size=32 style="font-size:18px">
    <label><font style="font-size:20px">Reads:</font></label>
    <select style="font-size:18px" name="select2" id="select2" >
        <option value="greaterthan" selected="selected">&gt;</option>
        <option value="greaterthanorequal">&ge;</option>
        <option value="lessthan">&lt;</option>
        <option value="lessthanorequal">&le;</option>
        <option value="equal">&#x3d;</option>
    </select>
    <input  type="text" name="reads" id="reads" placeholder="Eg:81007346" size=32 style="font-size:18px">
    <input type="button" name="submit">
</form>
```

i have two search fields where i want to search data with combination of select options using both the fields, i want to make the code short using switch case , i know how to write switch case for one field with select options. but in this case we have to search both search fields at a time with select options. can anybody help me how to write it.

Comment: do you want a single switch case for both selections?

Comment: Hi Alex, i need single switch case for both selection using sql query  or else any other type of method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_POST['bases']) && !empty($_POST['reads'])) 
 { 
  $valueB=$_POST['bases']; 
  $values40=$_POST['select1']; 
  $valueR=$_POST['reads']; 
  $values41=$_POST['select2']; 

  switch (true){ 
    case $values40=='greaterthan' && $values41=='greaterthan': 
      $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane,a.project,a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) > '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) > '$valueR' ";
    break; 
    case $values40=='greaterthan' && $values41=='greaterthanorequal': 
      $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane,a.project,a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) > '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) >= '$valueR' ";
    break; 
    case $values40=='greaterthan' && $values41=='lessthan': 
      $sql="SELECT a.run,a.lane,a.project,a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) > '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) < '$valueR' ";
    break; 
    case $values40=='greaterthan' && $values41=='lessthanorequal': 
      $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) > '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) <= '$valueR' ";
    break; 
    case $values40=='greaterthan' && $values41=='equal': 
     $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) > '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) = '$valueR' ";
   break; 
   case $values40=='greaterthanorequal' && $values41=='greaterthan': 
     $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) >= '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) > '$valueR' ";
   break; 
   case $values40=='greaterthanorequal' && $values41=='greaterthanorequal': 
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) >= '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) >= '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='greaterthanorequal' && $values41=='lessthan': 
      $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) >= '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) < '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='greaterthanorequal' && $values41=='lessthanorequal': 
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) >= '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) <= '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='greaterthanorequal' && $values41=='equal': 
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) >= '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) = '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='lessthan' && $values41=='greaterthan': 
      $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) < '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) > '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='lessthan' && $values41=='greaterthanorequal': 
             $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) < '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) >= '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='lessthan' && $values41=='lessthan': 
         $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) < '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) < '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='lessthan' && $values41=='lessthanorequal': 
        $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) < '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) <= '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='lessthan' && $values41=='equal': 
    $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) < '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) = '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='lessthanorequal' && $values41=='greaterthan': 
     $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) <= '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) > '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='lessthanorequal' && $values41=='greaterthanorequal': 
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) <= '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) >= '$valueR' ";
 break; 
  case $values40=='lessthanorequal' && $values41=='lessthan': 
     $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) <= '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) < '$valueR' ";
break; 
 case $values40=='lessthanorequal' && $values41=='lessthanorequal': 
   $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) <= '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) <= '$valueR' ";
 break; 
 case $values40=='lessthanorequal' && $values41=='equal': 
  $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) <= '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) = '$valueR' ";
break; 
 case $values40=='equal' && $values41=='greaterthan': 
 $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) = '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) > '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='equal' && $values41=='greaterthanorequal': 
     $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) = '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) >= '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='equal' && $values41=='lessthan': 
     $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) = '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) < '$valueR' ";
  break; 
  case $values40=='equal' && $values41=='lessthanorequal': 
     $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) = '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) <= '$valueR' ";
break; 
case $values40=='equal' && $values41=='equal': 
    $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) = '$valueB' AND (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) = '$valueR' ";
break;
```

}

}

Comment: is it possible to give two values in switch ($value1 & &value2),

Comment: because we r using two selects here

Comment: if (!empty($_POST['bases']) && !empty($_POST['reads']))
         {
     $valueB=$_POST['bases'];
          $values40=$_POST['select1'];
          $valueR=$_POST['reads'];
          $values41=$_POST['select2'];

Comment: if ($values40=='greaterthan' && $values41=='greaterthan')
            {
            $sql="query ";
            } 
            elseif ($values40=='greaterthan' && $values41=='greaterthanorequal')
            {
            $sql="query' ";
            }

Comment: elseif ($values40=='lessthan' && $values41=='greaterthan')
            {
            $sql="query ";
            }
            elseif ($values40=='lessthan' && $values41=='greaterthanorequal')
            {
            $sql="query ";
            }

Comment: try switch (true)

Comment: if i take one value in switch what about second select value and we should give two value in case as well

Comment: @vinod please add all relevant information to your question so that the full story is all in one place .

Comment: @mickmackusa plz provide me ur email id so that i can mail my script with proper description

Comment: @vinod That is not how SO works; it would be unfair if only I had all of the information.  If you cannot squeeze the relevant information into the body of your question, then chances are that your have not isolated your question to a single issue (and it may be flagged as "too broad").  This is not a free coding service.  SO requires that you provide a coding attempt.  If you know how to write a switch statement, include it in your question.  Please update your question with an Edit.

Comment: if (!empty($_POST['bases']) && !empty($_POST['reads']))
         {
     $valueB=$_POST['bases'];
          $values40=$_POST['select1'];
          $valueR=$_POST['reads'];
          $values41=$_POST['select2'];
          switch(true)
           {
            case ($values40='greaterthan' && $values41='greaterthan'):
        
               $sql="query' ";
              break;
            case ($values40='greaterthan' && $values41='lessthan'):
              $sql="query' ";
             break;
} }

Comment: am adding some modification to it

Comment: I don't  have any php editor right now so am doing it with notepad there may be some modifications sorry if i miss anything

Comment: sorry guys for wasting ur time

Comment: one small mistake made to waste ur time

Comment: i used case ($values40='greaterthan' && $values41='lessthan')

Comment: instead of ($values40==greaterthan' && $values41=='lessthan')  , i missed  "equal to" in case statement

Comment: sorry for that i don't have any resources currently to check